# csvtojson not working inside protractor then

Tags: json, node.js, csv, protractor, e2e-testing

so basically i want to download a csv file then convert it to json, but currently the problem i'm getting is that the function which converts the csv to json is not working inside protractor then, the method "converter.fromFile" printing empty array. below is my code

```
var createUser = require('../pages/createUser.page.js');
var exportPermissions = require('../pages/exportPermissions.page.js');
var cred = require('../../local.credentials.js');
var globals = require('./../../globals.js');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var fs = require('fs')
var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var URL = 'http://' + cred.httpAuth + '@' + cred.server + '/#/page/login';
const csvFilePath='C:/Users/Manoor khan/Downloads/System___exportedPermissions.csv';


var converter = new Converter({});
var permissions;
describe('Use case: MEP-T96 Export permissions', function () {

var createUserSelectors;
var loginPg;
var permissionsMenu;
beforeAll(function () {
    createUserSelectors = new createUser();
    permissionsMenu = new exportPermissions();
    browser.get(URL).then(function () {
        console.log('opened URL');
    });
});
it('MEP-T96 Export permissions', function (done) {
    globals.login('adminUname', 'adminPass').then(function () { console.log('Logged in as admin') });
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(createUserSelectors.adminPage), 20000, 'admin Page taking too long to appear in the DOM');
    createUserSelectors.administrationMenu.click().then(function () { console.log('Clicked adminstration menue') });
    expect(createUserSelectors.userManagerMenu.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Couldnt find manager user link');
    expect(permissionsMenu.systemPermissionMenu.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'couldnt find create system permission link');
    permissionsMenu.systemPermissionMenu.click().then(function () { console.log('Clicked on system permissions menu') });
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(permissionsMenu.permissionSearchBtn), 20000, 'Permission page didnt load in the given time');
    expect(permissionsMenu.permissionSearchBtn.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Permission search button not found');
    expect(permissionsMenu.permissionSearchBar.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Permission search bar not found');
    expect(permissionsMenu.exportPermissionsAsCSVBtn.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Export permission button not found');
    permissionsMenu.exportPermissionsAsCSVBtn.click().then(function () { console.log('Clicked on export permission button') });
    permissionsMenu.downloadCVSbutton.click().then(function(){
        console.log('Clicked on the download CVS button');
        }).then(function(){
        if (fs.existsSync(csvFilePath)) {
            console.log('found');
            converter.fromFile(csvFilePath,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("An Error Has Occured");
                    console.log(err);  
                } 
               //permissions = result;
               console.log(csvFilePath);
               console.log(result);
               });
            } else {
                console.log('didnt find');
            }


    }).then(function(){

    }).then(function(){
        fs.unlink(csvFilePath, function(){
            console.log('--->done');
        });
     });
```

Comment: Please give the running log?   Have you do a quick test on your code (without protractor part) on  an downloaded csv file to check it can also work individually

Comment: yes i did run the test without protractor on a downloaded file it was working fine then

Comment: @yong please check my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
    // combine csv header row and csv line to a json object
    // jsonObj.a ==> 1 or 4
})
.on('done',(error)=>{
    console.log('end')
})
```

Try this ^

And also try that your file path doesn't contain any spaces.

If you need promise, try

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter;
Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);

var converter = new Converter();

converter.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then(function(data){console.log(data)})
```

Comment: let me try that as well